# To remove data from the database and keep it somewhere else which I can treat as a entity

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, teiid, data-virtualization

I have a Spring Boot project. Currently, I have a datasource which is having all the data which also comprises of some config tables. We are thinking of keeping some of the config data out of our datasource and maintaining it somewhere else, but we want to treat them as entities and repositories by which we can fetch the data by the same way as we do now.

I started integrating Teiid with Spring Boot, but was not much of any help.
Is there any other technology/ideas by which we can achieve this.

Please let me know if anyone of you has more questions/doubts about this.

Teiid Spring Boot. Teiid embedded server is working fine and I'm able to query them. But incorporating it with the existing datasource lead to many complexities.

Comment: This question is very vague, Teiid Spring Boot is built using Teiid Embedded, working in one not in other? Yes I can tell you that your use case is valid. If ask about specific issue or questions I can help answer.

Comment: What I mean't was Teiid Spring Boot is working fine when I have just the Teiid embedded database, but when I incorporate Teiid embedded with another datasource, Teiid is trying to connect to my other datasource, what i want is keep both of them seperate. Does that answer your doubt?

Comment: When Teiid Spring Boot is available, yes it tries to read from all the data sources that are also configured, such that it can provide the single access layer. Any access to data sources is expected through the Teiid. However, you are free to directly use data source too, but any of the `spring data` wiring will be using Teiid.  facade. What is the issue you are seeing with this?

Comment: I don't' want Teiid to bind with the existing datasource. I want Teiid to read from the CSV files and not from the configured datasource(eg. bdsdatasource). I have made separate configuration for bdsdatasource with @PersistanceContext for those repositories. Now Teiid is trying to bind itself to bdsdatasource. Please help me resolve with this.

Comment: Currently that is not possible, if you want you can request a feature request on our jira system. Otherwise you can use Teiid as  the persistence context as I mentioned before.